# Unicode characters on ZPL printer

Tags: printing, zpl, zpl-ii

I have the task of re-designing a system to print shipping labels, using a networked Zebra GK420T. I have been able to send ZPL print jobs to it perfectly fine, but I cannot seem to get it to print unicode characters, such as cyrillic letters. I have downloaded the lucida sans unicode font to the printer using the Seagull Scientific drivers and I am using the following ZPL code to test:

```
^XA
^LH100,150
^CI28
^FT0,0^A@N,50,50,R:LUCIDASR.FNT^CI28^FDTesting 1 2 3^FS
^FT0,50^A@N,50,50,R:LUCIDASR.FNT^CI28^FDДо свидания^FS
^FT0,100^B3^FDAAA001^FS
^XZ
```

It will print the 'Testing 1 2 3' and the barcode, but it leaves a blank space instead of the cyrillic characters.

I also tried using the Zebra swiss unicode font and now it prints the russian characters as question marks:

```
^XA
^LH100,150
^CWT,E:TT0003M_.FNT
^CFT,30,30
^CI28
^FT0,0^FDTesting 1 2 3^FS
^FT0,50^FDДо свидания^FS
^FT0,100^B3^FDAAA001^FS
^XZ
```

Am I doing something wrong like not escaping characters or something or is it a problem with the printer?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I just discovered that you need to escape characters above ASCII by first putting `^FH` before any `^FD` fields that could contain a utf character and you need to prefix the utf-8 hex code with an underscore

`_D0_94` will print as Д. My final ZPL code is as follows:

```
^XA
^LH100,150
^CWT,E:TT0003M_.FNT
^CFT,30,30
^CI28
^FT0,0^FH^FDTesting 1 2 3^FS
^FT0,50^FH^FD_D0_94_D0_BE _D1_81_D0_B2_D0_B8_D0_B4_D0_B0_D0_BD_D0_B8_D1_8F^FS
^FT0,100^B3^FDAAA001^FS
^XZ
```

I'm just going to have to make a way to generate the escape sequences, which should be much easier!

Comment: Must note that it works withoust escaping. All you need to do is encode file or string you are sending to printer to `UTF-8`. Tested on `Zebra GK420t`.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the `^CI` command determines the encoding. Make sure your zpl code has `^CI28` if your text is in utf-8.

Comment: @MakSim that doesn't work with Zebra GK420k, I switched to utf8 on notepad++, sent the file and it didn't print unicode. Perhaps it has to do with the default font.

Comment: @MakSim OK I downloaded an arial font, switched the D font with arial font: ^CWD,E:ARI001.FNT and wrote ^ADN,30,30^FD and utf-8 glyphs show up without escaping.

Comment: @Lidor I'm so sorry but I can't get ^CI28 to output anything! I've tried a simple `^XA^CI28^A0N,34^FH^FVR_F6BIN^XZ` Is supposed to print "RÖBIN" but comes out as "RBIN". Any advice?

Comment: @RobinJonsson isn't it supposed to be `_C3_96` instead of `_F6`? You might also want to try just entering `Ö` without escaping it.

Comment: @Lidor Thanks so much for your reply. I was looking for the wrong code. F6 is the unicode code point for ö. For instance, say that I can't change to _C3_96, I see that F6 is the hex for ö in ISO-8859-1. Any way to specify that encoding? 
Regards, and so thankful for your comment!

Comment: @RobinJonsson Try looking at the `^CI` [command documentation](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf). `^CI31` might be what you're after.

Comment: How do you get `_D0_94` will print `Д`? Any reference link?

Comment: I got it from here - http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm?start=1024

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem, you should add an `^FH`(Field Hexadecimal Indicator) before any `^FD`(Field Data) command that contains special characters, in my case I need spanish chars so I had to use `^CI28`(Change International Font/Encoding)

[UTF 8 HEX codes list](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/)

sample: to print `Alvaro Jesús Pérez Peñaranda`
we need to convert those special characters to UTF 8 Hex code and add an _ before each code, this is the result: `Alvaro Jes_c3_bas P_c3_a9rez Pe_c3_b1aranda`

```
^XA

^CI28
^FO60,75
^ASN,36,20^FH^FDAlvaro Jes_c3_bas P_c3_a9rez Pe_c3_b1aranda^FS

^XZ
```

Comment: This looks what I need. How do you convert your String into this special Hex? are you running it from Android?

Comment: Looking at the ZPL II documentation the CI range only goes up to 26 (page 109 under ^CI "Change International Font")

Answer (score 8):

I'm using Zebra ZM400 printer and use TT0003M_ font.

this font does not print kazakh cyrillic.

if you want to print cryillic + kazakh cyrillic + latin alphabet, use ARI000.FNT (arial font)

I'm using the following method convert char to hex code

I hope this helps

```
stringConverTextToHex(stringtext)
{
stringnewText="";
char[]charArray=text.ToCharArray();
foreach(charcincharArray)
{
switch(c)
{
case'й':
newText+="_D0_B9";
break;
case'Й':
newText+="_D0_99";
break;
case'ц':
newText+="_D1_86";
break;
case'Ц':
newText+="_D0_A6";
break;
case'у':
newText+="_D1_83";
break;
case'У':
newText+="_D0_A3";
break;
case'к':
newText+="_D0_BA";
break;
case'К':
newText+="_D0_9A";
break;
case'е':
newText+="_D0_B5";
break;
case'Е':
newText+="_D0_95";
break;
case'н':
newText+="_D0_BD";
break;
case'Н':
newText+="_D0_9D";
break;
case'г':
newText+="_D0_B3";
break;
case'Г':
newText+="_D0_93";
break;
case'ш':
newText+="_D1_88";
break;
case'Ш':
newText+="_D0_A8";
break;
case'щ':
newText+="_D1_89";
break;
case'Щ':
newText+="_D0_A9";
break;
case'з':
newText+="_D0_B7";
break;
case'З':
newText+="_D0_97";
break;
case'х':
newText+="_D1_85";
break;
case'Х':
newText+="_D0_A5";
break;
case'ъ':
newText+="_D1_8A";
break;
case'Ъ':
newText+="_D0_AA";
break;
case'ф':
newText+="_D1_84";
break;
case'Ф':
newText+="_D0_A4";
break;
case'ы':
newText+="_D1_8B";
break;
case'Ы':
newText+="_D0_AB";
break;
case'в':
newText+="_D0_B2";
break;
case'В':
newText+="_D0_92";
break;
case'а':
newText+="_D0_B0";
break;
case'А':
newText+="_D0_90";
break;
case'п':
newText+="_D0_BF";
break;
case'П':
newText+="_D0_9F";
break;
case'р':
newText+="_D1_80";
break;
case'Р':
newText+="_D0_A0";
break;
case'о':
newText+="_D0_BE";
break;
case'О':
newText+="_D0_9E";
break;
case'л':
newText+="_D0_BB";
break;
case'Л':
newText+="_D0_9B";
break;
case'д':
newText+="_D0_B4";
break;
case'Д':
newText+="_D0_94";
break;
case'ж':
newText+="_D0_B6";
break;
case'Ж':
newText+="_D0_96";
break;
case'э':
newText+="_D1_8D";
break;
case'Э':
newText+="_D0_AD";
break;
case'я':
newText+="_D1_8F";
break;
case'Я':
newText+="_D0_AF";
break;
case'ч':
newText+="_D1_87";
break;
case'Ч':
newText+="_D0_A7";
break;
case'с':
newText+="_D1_81";
break;
case'С':
newText+="_D0_A1";
break;
case'м':
newText+="_D0_BC";
break;
case'М':
newText+="_D0_9C";
break;
case'и':
newText+="_D0_B8";
break;
case'И':
newText+="_D0_98";
break;
case'т':
newText+="_D1_82";
break;
case'Т':
newText+="_D0_A2";
break;
case'ь':
newText+="_D1_8C";
break;
case'Ь':
newText+="_D0_AC";
break;
case'б':
newText+="_D0_B1";
break;
case'Б':
newText+="_D0_91";
break;
case'ю':
newText+="_D1_8E";
break;
case'Ю':
newText+="_D0_AE";
break;
case'ӑ':
newText+="_D3_91";
break;
case'Ӑ':
newText+="_D3_90";
break;
case'ӓ':
newText+="_D3_93";
break;
case'Ӓ':
newText+="_D3_92";
break;
case'ә':
newText+="_D3_99";
break;
case'Ә':
newText+="_D3_98";
break;
case'ӛ':
newText+="_D3_9B";
break;
case'Ӛ':
newText+="_D3_9A";
break;
case'ӕ':
newText+="_D3_95";
break;
case'Ӕ':
newText+="_D3_94";
break;
case'ґ':
newText+="_D2_91";
break;
case'Ґ':
newText+="_D2_90";
break;
case'ѓ':
newText+="_D1_93";
break;
case'Ѓ':
newText+="_D0_83";
break;
case'ғ':
newText+="_D2_93";
break;
case'Ғ':
newText+="_D2_92";
break;
case'ӷ':
newText+="_D3_B7";
break;
case'Ӷ':
newText+="_D3_B6";
break;
case'ҕ':
newText+="_D2_95";
break;
case'Ҕ':
newText+="_D2_94";
break;
case'ђ':
newText+="_D1_92";
break;
case'Ђ':
newText+="_D0_82";
break;
case'ѐ':
newText+="_D1_90";
break;
case'Ѐ':
newText+="_D0_80";
break;
case'ӗ':
newText+="_D3_97";
break;
case'Ӗ':
newText+="_D3_96";
break;
case'ҽ':
newText+="_D2_BD";
break;
case'Ҽ':
newText+="_D2_BC";
break;
case'ҿ':
newText+="_D2_BF";
break;
case'Ҿ':
newText+="_D2_BE";
break;
case'є':
newText+="_D1_94";
break;
case'Є':
newText+="_D0_84";
break;
case'ӂ':
newText+="_D3_82";
break;
case'Ӂ':
newText+="_D3_81";
break;
case'җ':
newText+="_D2_97";
break;
case'Җ':
newText+="_D2_96";
break;
case'ӝ':
newText+="_D3_9D";
break;
case'Ӝ':
newText+="_D3_9C";
break;
case'ҙ':
newText+="_D2_99";
break;
case'Ҙ':
newText+="_D2_98";
break;
case'ӟ':
newText+="_D3_9F";
break;
case'Ӟ':
newText+="_D3_9E";
break;
case'ӡ':
newText+="_D3_A1";
break;
case'Ӡ':
newText+="_D3_A0";
break;
case'ѕ':
newText+="_D1_95";
break;
case'Ѕ':
newText+="_D0_85";
break;
case'ѝ':
newText+="_D1_9D";
break;
case'Ѝ':
newText+="_D0_8D";
break;
case'ӥ':
newText+="_D3_A5";
break;
case'Ӥ':
newText+="_D3_A4";
break;
case'ӣ':
newText+="_D3_A3";
break;
case'Ӣ':
newText+="_D3_A2";
break;
case'і':
newText+="_D1_96";
break;
case'І':
newText+="_D0_86";
break;
case'ї':
newText+="_D1_97";
break;
case'Ї':
newText+="_D0_87";
break;
case'Ӏ':
newText+="_D3_80";
break;
case'ҋ':
newText+="_D2_8B";
break;
case'Ҋ':
newText+="_D2_8A";
break;
case'ј':
newText+="_D1_98";
break;
case'Ј':
newText+="_D0_88";
break;
case'қ':
newText+="_D2_9B";
break;
case'Қ':
newText+="_D2_9A";
break;
case'ҟ':
newText+="_D2_9F";
break;
case'Ҟ':
newText+="_D2_9E";
break;
case'ҡ':
newText+="_D2_A1";
break;
case'Ҡ':
newText+="_D2_A0";
break;
case'ӄ':
newText+="_D3_84";
break;
case'Ӄ':
newText+="_D3_83";
break;
case'ҝ':
newText+="_D2_9D";
break;
case'Ҝ':
newText+="_D2_9C";
break;
case'ӆ':
newText+="_D3_86";
break;
case'Ӆ':
newText+="_D3_85";
break;
case'љ':
newText+="_D1_99";
break;
case'Љ':
newText+="_D0_89";
break;
case'ӎ':
newText+="_D3_8E";
break;
case'Ӎ':
newText+="_D3_8D";
break;
case'ӊ':
newText+="_D3_8A";
break;
case'Ӊ':
newText+="_D3_89";
break;
case'ң':
newText+="_D2_A3";
break;
case'Ң':
newText+="_D2_A2";
break;
case'ӈ':
newText+="_D3_88";
break;
case'Ӈ':
newText+="_D3_87";
break;
case'ҥ':
newText+="_D2_A5";
break;
case'Ҥ':
newText+="_D2_A4";
break;
case'њ':
newText+="_D1_9A";
break;
case'Њ':
newText+="_D0_8A";
break;
case'ӧ':
newText+="_D3_A7";
break;
case'Ӧ':
newText+="_D3_A6";
break;
case'ө':
newText+="_D3_A9";
break;
case'Ө':
newText+="_D3_A8";
break;
case'ӫ':
newText+="_D3_AB";
break;
case'Ӫ':
newText+="_D3_AA";
break;
case'ҩ':
newText+="_D2_A9";
break;
case'Ҩ':
newText+="_D2_A8";
break;
case'ҧ':
newText+="_D2_A7";
break;
case'Ҧ':
newText+="_D2_A6";
break;
case'ҏ':
newText+="_D2_8F";
break;
case'Ҏ':
newText+="_D2_8E";
break;
case'ҫ':
newText+="_D2_AB";
break;
case'Ҫ':
newText+="_D2_AA";
break;
case'ҭ':
newText+="_D2_AD";
break;
case'Ҭ':
newText+="_D2_AC";
break;
case'ћ':
newText+="_D1_9B";
break;
case'Ћ':
newText+="_D0_8B";
break;
case'ќ':
newText+="_D1_9C";
break;
case'Ќ':
newText+="_D0_8C";
break;
case'ў':
newText+="_D1_9E";
break;
case'Ў':
newText+="_D0_8E";
break;
case'ӳ':
newText+="_D3_B3";
break;
case'Ӳ':
newText+="_D3_B2";
break;
case'ӱ':
newText+="_D3_B1";
break;
case'Ӱ':
newText+="_D3_B0";
break;
case'ӯ':
newText+="_D3_AF";
break;
case'Ӯ':
newText+="_D3_AE";
break;
case'ү':
newText+="_D2_AF";
break;
case'Ү':
newText+="_D2_AE";
break;
case'ұ':
newText+="_D2_B1";
break;
case'Ұ':
newText+="_D2_B0";
break;
case'ҳ':
newText+="_D2_B3";
break;
case'Ҳ':
newText+="_D2_B2";
break;
case'һ':
newText+="_D2_BB";
break;
case'Һ':
newText+="_D2_BA";
break;
case'ҵ':
newText+="_D2_B5";
break;
case'Ҵ':
newText+="_D2_B4";
break;
case'ӵ':
newText+="_D3_B5";
break;
case'Ӵ':
newText+="_D3_B4";
break;
case'ҷ':
newText+="_D2_B7";
break;
case'Ҷ':
newText+="_D2_B6";
break;
case'ӌ':
newText+="_D3_8C";
break;
case'Ӌ':
newText+="_D3_8B";
break;
case'ҹ':
newText+="_D2_B9";
break;
case'Ҹ':
newText+="_D2_B8";
break;
case'џ':
newText+="_D1_9F";
break;
case'Џ':
newText+="_D0_8F";
break;
case'ӹ':
newText+="_D3_B9";
break;
case'Ӹ':
newText+="_D3_B8";
break;
case'ҍ':
newText+="_D2_8D";
break;
case'Ҍ':
newText+="_D2_8C";
break;
case'ӭ':
newText+="_D3_AD";
break;
case'Ӭ':
newText+="_D3_AC";
break;
case'A':
newText+="_41";
break;
case'a':
newText+="_61";
break;
case'B':
newText+="_42";
break;
case'b':
newText+="_62";
break;
case'C':
newText+="_43";
break;
case'c':
newText+="_63";
break;
case'D':
newText+="_44";
break;
case'd':
newText+="_64";
break;
case'E':
newText+="_45";
break;
case'e':
newText+="_65";
break;
case'F':
newText+="_46";
break;
case'f':
newText+="_66";
break;
case'G':
newText+="_47";
break;
case'g':
newText+="_67";
break;
case'H':
newText+="_48";
break;
case'h':
newText+="_68";
break;
case'I':
newText+="_49";
break;
case'i':
newText+="_69";
break;
case'J':
newText+="_4A";
break;
case'j':
newText+="_6A";
break;
case'K':
newText+="_4B";
break;
case'k':
newText+="_6B";
break;
case'L':
newText+="_4C";
break;
case'l':
newText+="_6C";
break;
case'M':
newText+="_4D";
break;
case'm':
newText+="_6D";
break;
case'N':
newText+="_4E";
break;
case'n':
newText+="_6E";
break;
case'O':
newText+="_4F";
break;
case'o':
newText+="_6F";
break;
case'P':
newText+="_50";
break;
case'p':
newText+="_70";
break;
case'R':
newText+="_52";
break;
case'r':
newText+="_72";
break;
case'S':
newText+="_53";
break;
case's':
newText+="_73";
break;
case'T':
newText+="_54";
break;
case't':
newText+="_74";
break;
case'U':
newText+="_55";
break;
case'u':
newText+="_75";
break;
case'V':
newText+="_56";
break;
case'v':
newText+="_76";
break;
case'Y':
newText+="_59";
break;
case'y':
newText+="_79";
break;
case'Z':
newText+="_5A";
break;
case'z':
newText+="_7A";
break;
case'':
newText+="";
break;
default:
newText+=c;
break;
}
}
returnnewText;
}
```

this is the sample code

---

^SP
^XA
^PON^FS
^FPH^FO102,63,0
^A@N,60,60,E:ARIOOO_.FNT
^FH^FD_42_75_72_61_6B _D0_A8_D3_99
^FS
^XZ

---

Comment: mostly Zebra Printer doesn't support cryillic + kazakh cyrillic + latin alphabet and Your function `stringConverTextToHex` most helpful. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Russian and many other characters can be printed using the free [Zebra swiss unicode font](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO6820&actp=RSS). It is already included in most printers as TT0003M_ and supports Roman, Cyrillic, Eastern European, Turkish, Arabic, Hebrew.

---

For printing languages like Japanese or Chinese, which have thousands of characters, you need a printer with at least 23 MB of free memory and a TrueType font file you can upload (they call it download).

This file can be bought from Zebra (and they say you need 64 MB), but I was also very successful with a very old TTF file found on my Windows 7 system in the Fonts folder: ARIALUNI.TTF 1.01 (23.275.812 Bytes), [Arial Unicode MS](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1081). It was installed by a MS Office installation and is maybe not licensed for this use.

Most likely you can also use other TTF files, but I tried only this one.

While ZPL-printing on this Zebra printer worked without any original driver (just generic text only), for the font installation the driver was needed. If anyone knows how to send the TTF file to the printer without driver, please comment.

I installed the Zebra Setup Utilities, which include a Fonts Downloader. Click new, then add the font (must be installed in the system), and ignore the message that 226 characters are included. Also ignore that if you configure a test string with Unicode characters, it will not display correctly. You are beeing asked if you want to download now and it takes a long time.

You can check the installation by listing the directory contents (Administration web page or printout). There the font appears as ARI000.TTF in my case.

---

To print, you need to send the ZPL text as UTF-8. You can copy this example to notepad and select UTF-8 in the save dialog:

```
^XA
^LH100,150
^CWT,E:ARI000.FNT
^CFT,30,30
^CI28
^FT0,0^FH^FDyour unicode characters here^FS
^XZ
```

Then, for testing, you can use a simple copy command to send it to the printer:

In case of USB you need to share this printer in the network first.

Then `net use lpt1: \\localhost\sharename`
and `copy file.txt lpt1`

We tested with many common Japanese and Chinese symbols and it works very well with high quality, on a ZT230 printer with 32 MB flash.

Answer (score 3):

Your "До свидания" were probably in cp1251. Encode it in actual UTF-8 and try again. Blank spaces are a good indicator that you have an encoding problem.

Verified with v56.17.112 firmware and  ^A@N,,,E:TT0003M_.FNT

Comment: This is the best answer. It is really not necessary to use hex codes or whatever. You can just send the real unicode characters and it works. For Japanese and Chinese characters this font doesn't work. But I found a free solution for this too. Let me see where to post it... Will update here.

Answer (score 3):

if you want print Russian Cyrillic letters using `:TT0003M_.FNT`, you should save commands to file with UTF-8 encoding!

```
^XA
^LH100,150
^CWT,E:TT0003M_.FNT
^CFT,30,30
^CI28
^FT0,0^FH^FDTesting 1 2 3^FS
^FT0,30^FH^FDДо свидания^FS
^FT0,100^B3^FDAAA001^FS
^XZ
```

Then, using command line you can send it to printer port.
An example: copy C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test_ru.txt com1

I hope that will help...

Comment: This handy copy command also works with USB and LAN connection. Just use "net use lpt1: \\server\printer"

Answer (score 3):

You can replace character that greater then one byte to UTF-8 hex string with underscore like "ћ => _D1_9B". Sample code below;

```
 var zpl_code = "^XA" +
        "^LH100,150" +
        "^CWT,E:TT0003M_.FNT" +
        "^CFT,30,30" +
        "^CI28" +
        "^FT0,0^FDTesting 1 2 3^FS" +
        "^FT0,50^FDДо свидания^FS" +
        "^FT0,100^B3^FDAAA001^FS" +
        "^XZ";
        var unicodeCharacterList = zpl_code.Distinct()
            .Select(c => c.ToString())
            .Select(c => new { key = c, UTF8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c) })
            .Where(c => c.UTF8Bytes.Length > 1);

        foreach (var character in unicodeCharacterList)
        {
            var characterHexCode = string.Join("", character.UTF8Bytes.Select(c => "_" + BitConverter.ToString(new byte[] { c }).ToLower()).ToArray());

            zpl_code = zpl_code.Replace(character.key, characterHexCode);
        }
```

This code set zpl_code variable to below output

```
^XA
^LH100,150
^CWT,E:TT0003M_.FNT
^CFT,30,30
^CI28
^FT0,0^FDTesting 1 2 3^FS
^FT0,50^FD_d0_94_d0_be _d1_81_d0_b2_d0_b8_d0_b4_d0_b0_d0_bd_d0_b8_d1_8f^FS
^FT0,100^B3^FDAAA001^FS
^XZ
```

Comment: in you example ZPL code you have forgotten the ^FH statment. The 7th line should be: ^FT0,50^FH^FD_d0_94_d0_be _d1_81_d0_b2_d0_b8_d0_b4_d0_b0_d0_bd_d0_b8_d1_8f^FS

Comment: Why the output does not include ^FH ?

Answer (score 3):

In latest firmware versions (since v x.16.x) you can use ^CI33 for codepage Windows-1251 encoded text (and other codepages) without ^FH. See [manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

I took [Dysnomin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56353649/186750) answer and converted something over to Javascript.  His answer was in C#

To run it, just take your string object and call `variable.zplHexEncode()`  where the variable is your string.  This defaults to the _ for the escape character.  You will still have to prefix all you `^FD` fields with the `^FH` command.  Personally, I use something like the [doT](https://github.com/olado/doT) module to create my ZPL and fill in the fields with values with escaped characters.  YMMV.

```js
   const _Last1ByteCode = 0x7E;
   const _First2ByteCode = 0xA0;
   const _Last2ByteCode = 0xBF;
   const _Last3ByteCode = 0xFF;
   const _3ByteOffset = 0x40;
   const _ZplEscapeCharacter = '_';
   const _2BytePre = 'c2';
   const _3BytePre = 'c3';


String.prototype.zplHexEncode  = function(){
    var hex, i, escHex;
    var result = "";
    for (i=0; i< this.length; i++) {
        var charCode = this.charCodeAt(i);

        if (charCode <= _Last1ByteCode)
            result += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        else if (charCode >= _First2ByteCode && charCode <=_Last2ByteCode) {
            hex = charCode.toString(16);
            escHex =  ("0"+hex).slice(-2);
            result += _ZplEscapeCharacter+_2BytePre+_ZplEscapeCharacter+escHex; 
        }
        else if (charCode > _Last2ByteCode && charCode <=_Last3ByteCode) {
            charCode = charCode - _3ByteOffset;
            hex = charCode.toString(16);
            escHex =  ("0"+hex).slice(-2);
            result += _ZplEscapeCharacter+_3BytePre+_ZplEscapeCharacter+escHex; 
        }
        else
            result += '';
    }
    return result
}

var str = "This is a test with a unicode character¿";

console.log(str.zplHexEncode());
```

Comment: What is the first and last byte codes for Georgian language?

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, make sure to use `^CI28` (Change International Font/Encoding) and `^FH` (Field Hexadecimal Indicator) and escape any non-ascii utf8 characters with an underscore and their hex value.

However another answer included code to format the utf8 string using a gigantic switch-case block. Here is the method I use for encoding to utf8, it should be able to format any valid utf8 byte array.

To get the byte array from a string use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)`.

```cs
// From the wikipedia page on utf8 encoding - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8
    private const int _Last1ByteCodePointByte1 = 0x7F;
    private const int _First2ByteCodePointByte1 = 0xC0;
    private const int _Last2ByteCodePointByte1 = 0xDF;
    private const int _Last3ByteCodePointByte1 = 0xEF;
    private const int _Last4ByteCodePointByte1 = 0xF7;
    private const int _FirstMultiByteCodePointByte2 = 0x80;
    private const int _LastMultiByteCodePointByte2 = 0xBF;
    private const char _ZplMultiByteEscapeCharacter = '_';

/// <summary>
/// Encodes a sequence of utf8 bytes for printing with the ZPL language, this means escaping multi-byte characters with an underscore ('_') followed by the hex code
/// for each byte in the multi-byte characters.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="utf8Bytes">The bytes that make up the entire string, including bytes that need to be encoded and bytes that can be printed as-is.</param>
/// <returns>A string for printing with the ZPL language. Ie all multi-byte characters escaped with an underscore ('_') followed by the hex code for each byte.</returns>
/// <throws><see cref="ArgumentException"/> when <paramref name="utf8Bytes"/> isn't a valid utf8 encoding of a string.</throws>
/// <remarks>
/// Plan is to figure out how many bytes this character (code point) takes up, and if it's a 1 byte character, just use the character, but otherwise since it's a multi-byte 
/// character then use an underscore ('_') followed by the hex encoded byte and each other byte in this code point will also be encoded. If we start the loop but have bytes 
/// remaining in the current code point we know to hex encode this byte and continue.
/// </remarks>
private static string EncodeUtf8BytesForZPLIIPrinting(byte[] utf8Bytes)
{
    var contentWithMultiByteCharsEscaped = new List<char>();

    var multiByteCodePoint = new List<char>();
    var remainingBytesInCurrentCodePoint = 0;
    string errorMessage = null;

    foreach (byte utf8Byte in utf8Bytes)
    {
        if (remainingBytesInCurrentCodePoint > 0)
        {
            if (utf8Byte < _FirstMultiByteCodePointByte2 || utf8Byte > _LastMultiByteCodePointByte2)
            {
                errorMessage = $"The byte {utf8Byte.ToString("X2")} is not a valid as the second or later byte of a multi-byte utf8 character (codepoint).";
                break;
            }

            multiByteCodePoint.Add(_ZplMultiByteEscapeCharacter);
            AddHexValuesToListFromByte(multiByteCodePoint, utf8Byte);
            remainingBytesInCurrentCodePoint--;
            continue; // continue since we've dealt with this byte and don't want to flow on.
        }

        if (multiByteCodePoint.Any())
        {
            foreach (char c in multiByteCodePoint) contentWithMultiByteCharsEscaped.Add(c);
            multiByteCodePoint.Clear();
            // flow on to loop to see what to do with the current byte.
        }

        if (utf8Byte <= _Last1ByteCodePointByte1)
        {
            // 1 byte - no escaping
            contentWithMultiByteCharsEscaped.Add((char)utf8Byte);
        }
        else if (utf8Byte >= _First2ByteCodePointByte1 && utf8Byte <= _Last2ByteCodePointByte1)
        {
            // 2 bytes
            multiByteCodePoint.Add(_ZplMultiByteEscapeCharacter);
            AddHexValuesToListFromByte(multiByteCodePoint, utf8Byte);
            remainingBytesInCurrentCodePoint = 1;
        }
        else if (utf8Byte <= _Last3ByteCodePointByte1)
        {
            // 3 bytes
            multiByteCodePoint.Add(_ZplMultiByteEscapeCharacter);
            AddHexValuesToListFromByte(multiByteCodePoint, utf8Byte);
            remainingBytesInCurrentCodePoint = 2;
        }
        else if (utf8Byte <= _Last4ByteCodePointByte1)
        {
            // 4 bytes
            multiByteCodePoint.Add(_ZplMultiByteEscapeCharacter);
            AddHexValuesToListFromByte(multiByteCodePoint, utf8Byte);
            remainingBytesInCurrentCodePoint = 3;
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage = $"The byte {utf8Byte.ToString("X2")} is not a valid as the first byte of a utf8 character.";
            break;
        }
    }

    // if the last char was multiByte add it now.
    if (multiByteCodePoint.Any())
    {
        foreach (var c in multiByteCodePoint) contentWithMultiByteCharsEscaped.Add(c);
        multiByteCodePoint.Clear();
    }

    if (remainingBytesInCurrentCodePoint != 0 && errorMessage == null)
    {
        errorMessage = $"The last character didn't have enough bytes to finish the codepoint. It was a multi-byte character that needed {remainingBytesInCurrentCodePoint}" + 
            $" more byte{(remainingBytesInCurrentCodePoint == 1 ? null : "s")}.";
    }

    if (errorMessage != null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"The byte array was not a valid byte array for a utf8 string: {errorMessage}", nameof(utf8Bytes));
    }

    return new string(contentWithMultiByteCharsEscaped.ToArray());


    void AddHexValuesToListFromByte(List<char> list, byte @byte)
    {
        // A byte is <= 255 so will always fit in a 2-digit hex number, hence the 2 in "X2". The X means hex.
        foreach (char c in @byte.ToString("X2"))
        {
            list.Add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When we use CP1251 as system encoding it causes empty symbols in labels, if we write Cyrillic in ZPL code. CP1251 users could first force convert "До свидания" to UTF-8 and get:

Р”Рѕ СЃРІРёРґР°РЅРёСЏ

Replace До свидания in ZPL code with these strange symbols and get "До свидания" on the label. It works with tt0003m_.fnt with ^CI28, but IMHO it is better to use hex-codes instead.

Answer (score 0):

For Cyrillic it is enough to change ^CI28 to ^CI33

```
^XA
^LH100,150
^CWT,E:TT0003M_.FNT
^CFT,30,30
^CI33
^FT0,0^FDTesting 1 2 3^FS
^FT0,50^FDДо свидания^FS
^FT0,100^B3^FDAAA001^FS
^XZ
```

Comment: this doesn't work - for example tried https://labelary.com/viewer.html