# Print Cyrillic symbols in barcode with Zebra

Tags: printing, barcode, zebra-printers, zpl

I'd like to know if there is a way to print Cyrillic symbols in barcode using Zebra printer?

The printer is Zebra GK420t. Language is ZPL.

Opposite to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040822/unicode-characters-on-zpl-printer) I'd like to print not text but barcode that includes Cyrillic symbols which could be later recognized by scanner.

Code sample:

```
^XA
^LH10,40
^CWT,E:ARI000.FNT^CFT,20,20^CI28
^FO60,330^BCN,100,Y,Y^FD^Part^FS
^XZ
```

In my app i replace `^Part` with part code which contans Cyrillic letters. String is encoded to UTF-8 and byte array sent to printer:

`byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ZPLstring);`

Comment: Please post a sample of the ZPL string you are sending and what you expect to be the result that is printed on the label.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to print a bar code that includes Cyrillic symbols if you use the Code-128 bar code encoding.  You have to set the code page to 1251 for Cyrillic.

You should read the ZPL documentation and determine how to set the mode to use Code-128 and code page 1251.

http://www.idautomation.com/barcode-fonts/code-128/user-manual.html

The answer to this question might also help you out:
[Unicode characters on ZPL printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040822/unicode-characters-on-zpl-printer)

Comment: Thanks for answer. This link is mainly related to font, but in my case I'm using printer's ability to print barcode and if any unsupported char is faced in my data barcode won't show up.

Comment: For zebra printers you have to use ZPL to print bar codes. You can use a ZPL command to put the printer in the the mode for printing a Code 128 bar code using code page 1251.

Comment: I do. That is what I want. But what I have tried so far does not work. I'd like to get tips on how it was successfully done by someone.

Comment: Did you read the answer to the linked question I put when I  updated my answer?

Comment: Yeah, I have the same link in my question. And I've already used that method to print text in proper encoding. This does not work for barcodes so far.