# Zebra printer: how to print UTF-8 special character

Tags: encoding, utf-8, zebra-printers, printers, zpl

I need to print label with special character like degree (°).
I'm using qz print applet on my website.
How i can say to applet that i'm going to print UtF-8 character?
Because it doesn't print correctly.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to escape characters above ASCII by putting `^FH` (Field Hexadecimal Indicator) before any `^FD` field that might contain an UTF char and you also need to prefix the UTF Hex code with an underscore. Like happens in this other question: [Unicode characters on ZPL printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040822/unicode-characters-on-zpl-printer)

Comment: I haven't got properly a zebra printer. I've got a TSC TTP-245C with ZPL emulation activated. I tried to use the escape characters above but it doesn't work.