# Print characters with an acute in ZPL

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, zebra-printers, zpl

If I send the ZPL commands below to a Zebra printer, it prints `AmitiÙ`:

```
^XA
^FO50,20
^CI7
^A0N,25,15
^FD
Amitié
^FS
^XZ
```

- Note that the file encoding is `ANSI`.
- Note the use of the ZPL command `^CI7` (7 => Single Byte Encoding - France 1 Character Set).

On the other hand, if I send the ZPL commands below to a Zebra printer, it prints `Amitié` (which is what I actually need to get):

```
^XA
^FO50,20
^CI28
^A0N,25,15
^FD
Amitié
^FS
^XZ
```

- Note that the file encoding is `UTF-8`.
- Note the use of the ZPL command `^CI28` (28 => Unicode (UTF-8 encoding) - Unicode Character Set).

Do you know what's wrong in the first case?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 25):

Use UTF-8 by placing a `^CI28` command at the top of your ZPL template, eg

```
^XA
^CI28
^CF0,80
^FO70,40^FDavión^FS
^XZ
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the programing guide [document](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) from Zebra `^CI` using 7 will get you [Code Page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) with some specific character replacements. When you say you had the file encoded in ANSI, I assume you mean [Code Page Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) or [ISO-8859-1 (latin1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

The character `é` in Windows-1252 and latin1 is #00E9, but that's `Ú` in 850; you would want #0082 for `é` in 850.  Using `^CI7` you could apparently also get an `é` with #007B since that's one of the specific character replacements made with that command.

Using UTF8 (with `^CI28`) is probably the way to go since it's widely supported and understood, but note that you could also try `^CI27` (which may work even if you have an older version of the Zebra firmware that doesn't support `^CI28`) and that should get you code page 1252. If that doesn't work you'll need to encode your text using code page 850.

Answer (score 1):

If you copy and paste your first example into a text editor that can convert between UTF-8 and ANSI (Notepad++) you'll see that the first example is encoded as

```
^XA
^FO50,20
^CI7
^A0N,25,15
^FD
AmitiÃ©
^FS
^XZ
```

And this will be cause problems with your ZPL when rendered. See online examples for [ANSI](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&width=4&height=6&units=inches&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%5EFO50%2C20%0A%5ECI7%0A%5EA0N%2C100%0A%5EFD%0AAmiti%C3%A9%0A%5EFS%0A%5EXZ) and [UTF-8](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&width=4&height=6&units=inches&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%5EFO50%2C20%0A%5ECI28%0A%5EA0N%2C100%0A%5EFD%0AAmiti%C3%A9%0A%5EFS%0A%5EXZ).

To fix this you could encode your values first (for example as hex and then prefix with `^FH`)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to be able to do that:

- Define UTF-8 charset using **^CI28**
- Use Swiss unicode font. For my case I only needed to encode on a single line and I didn't want to change anything else on the document or printer settings. For that I used **^A@N,44,30,E:TT0003M_.TTF**. If you want to define the font for the whole document check the first link below.
- Prepared the string to recognize UTF-8 encoding with **^FH** immediately before **^FD**
- Encoded the document to replace non-ASCII characters with their HEX representation:

```cs
    private static string ZebraEncode(string text)
    {
        var ret = new StringBuilder();

        var unicodeCharacterList = new Dictionary<char, string>();
        foreach(var ch in text)
        {
            if (!unicodeCharacterList.ContainsKey(ch))
            {
                var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ch.ToString());
                if (bytes.Length > 1)
                {
                    var hexCode = string.Empty;
                    foreach(var b in bytes)
                    {
                        hexCode += $"_{BitConverter.ToString(new byte[] { b }).ToLower()}";
                    }

                    unicodeCharacterList[ch] = hexCode;
                }
                else
                    unicodeCharacterList[ch] = ch.ToString();

                ret.Append(unicodeCharacterList[ch]);
            }
            else
                ret.Append(unicodeCharacterList[ch]);
        };

        return ret.ToString();
    }
```

---

Info that I gathered in order to reach a solution:

- [Downloading and using fonts on zebra zpl printers](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/ait/downloading-and-using-fonts-on-zebra-zpl-printers.html)
- [ZPL Online editor](http://labelary.com/service.html)
- A mix from the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040822/unicode-characters-on-zpl-printer)