# After printer restart, settings are lost

Tags: printing, zebra-printers

I am using GX430t Zebra printer.

My problem is that after printer restart, printer is no longer printing special characters for Slovenia.

(example file for printing is below).

Example:
Printer is restarted and then we print example file from our application (we have our own app for printing labels). Slovenian characters are not printed:

[image]

Next step is to send that same file into printer via printer settings:

[image]

File is printed correctly:

[image]

What is even more interesting is that every file printed from our application is OK, after that step is done.

My question is: where does printer stores info about that? What I would like to do is include (if possible) this information into every file that I am printing, so regardless if printer was restarted or not, Slovenian characters will be printed correctly. Otherwise, we must use printer settings and sending example file to printer each time printer is restarted.

Example file with zebra language:

> ^XA^LH300,10^FO10,10^A0,20,20^FD                                     Šazoćeđa gostinstvo d.o.o.^FS^FO10,20 ^A0,20,20^FDIme polizdelka: ^FS^FO10,40 ^A0,35,35^FDŠABAN ŠAULIĆ^FS^FO10,80 ^A0,30,30^FDDatum predpriprave: 25.04.2018^FS^FO10,120 ^A0,30,30^FDUporabno najmanj do: 25.04.2018^FS^FO10,160 ^A0,20,20^FDOddelek predpriprave: Centralna predpriprava^FS^FO10,190 ^A0,30,30^FDOddelek finalizacije: HKJ_topla kuhinja^FS^FO10,230 ^A0,30,30^FDKoličina: 7 (nar.); 0 (dos.); 7 (ned.); kg^FS^FO10,265 ^FB650,12,, ^A0,20,20^FDSestavine: MOKA PSENICNA T500 1KG (aler.: Gluten; psenica;); SOL KAMENA ; JAJCNI MELANZ (aler.: Jajca;); MLEKO SVEZE 10L (aler.: Mleko;)^FS^FO10,560 ^A0,20,20^FDPripravil: Šaban Šaulić^FS^XZ

Comment: I would recommend looking up the ^CI command in the ZPL manual and choosing an encoding that matches what you are trying to do. Embed that command in your ZPL and you should be good.

Comment: @banno thanks a lot for your answer. Can you please provide an example (or embedd into my example) sample code with encoding?

Comment: FYI, you can set your printer up using a "Generic Text based" printer driver, and then ZPL strait from notepad to the printer using "print"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @banno - solution was to put proper encoding into .ZPL file. In my case, taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437279/print-characters-with-an-acute-in-zpl) it was enough to add `^CI28` after `^XA`