# zebra printer not printing latin characters

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I have a problem with zebra printer ZT410, i'm trying to print in latin characters such as ñ, ç and ò and so on.

```
^XA
^CI28
^MMT
^PW1040
^LL840
^A@N,50,49,E:STI000.FNT^FT50,-230^FH\^FDRajoy^FS
^A@N,50,49,E:STI000.FNT^FB1040,2,25,C^FT0,-421^FH\^FDThañk yòú fôr showing me that there are people^FS
^A@N,50,49,E:STI000.FNT^FB1040,1,0,C^FT0,-509^FH\^FDlike you in this world.^FS
^A@N,50,49,E:STI000.FNT^FB1040,1,0,C^FT0,-572^FH\^FD^FS
^A@N,50,49,E:STI000.FNT^FB1040,1,0,C^FT0,-635^FH\^FDLoveç you.^FS
^A@N,50,49,E:STI000.FNT^FB1040,1,0,C^FT0,-698^FH\^FDMarta.^FS
^A@N,50,49,E:STI000.FNT^FT50,-790^FH\^FDDavid^FS
^XZ
```

But instead of printing the special characters, they are omited, I've checked that the special font used (Stingray) contains all those characters, I don't know how to print them. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Edit: I actually fixed it by using ^CI27 instead of ^CI28 since I have an older version of the Zebra firmware that doesn't support ^CI28

Comment: Try looking up unicode characters: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=zpl+unicode

Comment: I've tried all recommended solutions, using ^CI28 as recommended and tried using the unicode code for the special characters, this last solution only prints the code but not the character

Comment: First, simplify what you are testing. Make it one line, standard font etc.. Second, I see you are changing the Hex character to \ rather than _.  I don't see you using that in the ZPL example. You may not even need it.

Comment: This might be applicable too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437279/print-characters-with-an-acute-in-zpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something simple that works with some of the text you have:

```
^XA
^CI28
^FO50,20^A0N,40,40^FDThañk yòú fôr showing me that there are people^FS
^XZ
```

Comment: Tried this, it only prints: Tha k y  f r showing me that there are people, when I try printing with CI29 or C30 the printer doesn't even print and has to be reset in order to print again

Comment: Have you tried calling Zebra Support to ask what they think?