# How to print French characters with an acute (like 'é') with a Zebra P4t printer

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, zebra-printers, codepages, zpl

My question is about printing French characters with an acute like: `é è à ô etc.` with a **Zebra P4t printer**.

Consider the ZPL instructions below:

```
^XA
^FO20,20
^CI28
^A0,20,20
^FD
Amitié
^FS
^XZ
```

I have put these instructions into a file encoded as UTF-8.

When I send this file to a Zebra GK420t printer, I get the expected result concerning the character with an acute `é` at the end of the French word `Amitié` that you can see above. It is printed properly.

Now, when I send this very same file to a Zebra P4t printer it prints something like `|-®` instead of the `é` character.

The firmware of the printer is SHCPT11z48.

Alos, if you consider the ZPL instructions below:

```
^XA
^FO20,60
^A0,20,20
^FD
Amitié
^FS
^XZ
```

I have put these instructions into a file encoded as ANSI.

Now, when I send this very same file to a Zebra P4t printer it prints `Ú` instead of the `é` character.
I really don't see where this character `Ú` is coming from.

What can I do to solve that problem?

Is a font missing in the printer?

Am I not sending compatible ZPL instructions?

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: Does your printer accept cpcl?

Comment: If you really want to use ZPL, maybe have a look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040822/unicode-characters-on-zpl-printer

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is P4t specific. None of the proposals in the link you suggest solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution without having to replace anything:

After the opening tag **^XA** add **^CI28**.

```
^XA^CI28
your content
^XZ
```

Zebra support talking about it [here](https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/Printing-with-International-Characters?language=en_US).

Answer (score 2):

You have to prefix the field with UTF-8 characters with `^FH` (*Field Hexadecimal Indicator*) and replace every UTF-8 character with their unicode hexadecimal code prefixed by an `_` ([list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm), example for [`é`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e9/index.htm)):

```
^XA
^FO20,20
^CI28
^A0,20,20
^FD
Amiti_C3_A9
^FS
^XZ
```

Comment: Thank you. Same comment as above: the problem is P4t specific. On a GK420t this code works. It doesn't on a P4t.

Comment: `You have to prefix the field with UTF-8 characters with ^FH` why doesn't the example use `^FH`?

Comment: Answering my own question, `^FH` is to **set** the separator, which is `_` by default, therefor not needed in the above example.

Comment: `^FH_^FDAmit_C3_A9^FS`works perfectly when the default have been changed