# ZPL print € and characters with an acute

Tags: character-encoding, zebra-printers, zpl

I'm trying to print labels with the euro sign (€) and with characters with an acute on (é, è, à, ë,...).

I have fixed the isolated problems of both:

The euro sign was fixed by adding ^CI0,21,36.

The acute problem was solved using ^CI28 and ^FDBelgi_C3_AB (to print België).

But I fail to find a way to make them both print because one if using CI0 and the other one is using CI28. How can print €, ë, é, è, à, ... all on one label?

Using CI28,21,36 also doesn't solve the issue.

I already looked at [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040822/unicode-characters-on-zpl-printer), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746328/how-to-print-french-characters-with-an-acute-like-%C3%A9-with-a-zebra-p4t-printer) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437279/print-characters-with-an-acute-in-zpl) and am using a Zebra ZD420 printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CP-1252 (^CI27) to print all those characters:

```
    ^XA
    ^CI27
    ^FO70,70^A0N30,30
    ^FH^FDprint _80, _EB, _E9, _E8, _E0, ... all on one label?^FS
    ^XZ
```

Full listing of hex values for CP-1252 can be found in the "Zebra Code Pages" section of the [ZPL manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf).

```
    ╔═════════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
    ║ Code    ║ ...0 ║ ...1 ║ ...2 ║ ...3 ║ ...4 ║ ...5 ║ ...6 ║ ...7 ║ ...8 ║ ...9 ║ ...A ║ ...B ║ ...C ║ ...D ║ ...E ║ ...F ║ 
    ╠═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
    ║ 2...    ║      ║ !    ║ "    ║ #    ║ $    ║ %    ║ &    ║ '    ║ (    ║ )    ║ *    ║ +    ║ ,    ║ -    ║ .    ║ /    ║ 
    ╠═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
    ║ 3...    ║ 0    ║ 1    ║ 2    ║ 3    ║ 4    ║ 5    ║ 6    ║ 7    ║ 8    ║ 9    ║ :    ║ ;    ║ <    ║ =    ║ >    ║ ?    ║
    ╠═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣ 
    ║ 4...    ║ @    ║ A    ║ B    ║ C    ║ D    ║ E    ║ F    ║ G    ║ H    ║ I    ║ J    ║ K    ║ L    ║ M    ║ N    ║ O    ║ 
    ╠═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
    ║ 5...    ║ P    ║ Q    ║ R    ║ S    ║ T    ║ U    ║ V    ║ W    ║ X    ║ Y    ║ Z    ║ [    ║ \    ║ ]    ║ ^    ║ _    ║
    ╠═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
    ║ 6...    ║ `    ║ a    ║ b    ║ c    ║ d    ║ e    ║ f    ║ g    ║ h    ║ i    ║ j    ║ k    ║ l    ║ m    ║ n    ║ o    ║
    ╠═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣ 
    ║ 7...    ║ p    ║ q    ║ r    ║ s    ║ t    ║ u    ║ v    ║ w    ║ x    ║ y    ║ z    ║ {    ║      ║      ║ }    ║ ~    ║ 
    ╠═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
    ║ 8...    ║ €    ║      ║ ‚    ║ ƒ    ║ „    ║ …    ║ †    ║ ‡    ║ ˆ    ║ ‰    ║ Š    ║ ‹    ║ Œ    ║      ║ Ž    ║      ║ 
    ╠═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
    ║ 9...    ║      ║ ‘    ║ ’    ║ “    ║ ”    ║ •    ║ –    ║ —    ║ ˜     ║ ™   ║ š    ║ ›    ║ œ    ║      ║ ž    ║ Ÿ    ║ 
    ╠═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
    ║ A...    ║      ║ ¡    ║ ¢    ║ £    ║ ¤    ║ ¥    ║ ¦    ║ §    ║ ¨    ║ ©    ║ ª    ║ «    ║ ¬    ║ -    ║ ®    ║ ¯    ║
    ╠═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
    ║ B...    ║ °    ║ ±    ║ ²    ║ ³    ║ ´    ║ µ    ║ ¶    ║ ·    ║ ¸    ║ ¹    ║ º    ║ »    ║ ¼    ║ ½    ║ ¾    ║ ¿    ║ 
    ╠═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
    ║ C...    ║ À    ║ Á    ║ Â    ║ Ã    ║ Ä    ║ Å    ║ Æ    ║ Ç    ║ È    ║ É    ║ Ê    ║ Ë    ║ Ì    ║ Í    ║ Î    ║ Ï    ║ 
    ╠═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
    ║ D...    ║ Ð    ║ Ñ    ║ Ò    ║ Ó    ║ Ô    ║ Õ    ║ Ö    ║ ×    ║ Ø    ║ Ù    ║ Ú    ║ Û    ║ Ü    ║ Ý    ║ Þ    ║ ß    ║ 
    ╠═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
    ║ E...    ║ à    ║ á    ║ â    ║ ã    ║ ä    ║ å    ║ æ    ║ ç    ║ è    ║ é    ║ ê    ║ ë    ║ ì    ║ í    ║ î    ║ ï    ║ 
    ╠═════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
    ║ F...    ║ ð    ║ ñ    ║ ò    ║ ó    ║ ô    ║ õ    ║ ö    ║ ÷    ║ ø    ║ ù    ║ ú    ║ û    ║ ü    ║ ý    ║ þ    ║ ÿ    ║ 
    ╚═════════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put both on the same label. See the example below.

```
^XA
^CI0,21,36
^FO100,20^A0N50,50^FD$0123^FS
^CI28,21,36
^FH^FO100,70^A0N50,50^FDBelgi_C3_AB^FS
^XZ
```