# How to print Georgian letters with zpl

Tags: android, printing, zpl

I have ZEBRA ZQ320 printer and want to print in Georgian letters. I've read [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040822/unicode-characters-on-zpl-printer), I printed Russian letters but not Georgian. I followed [this link](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/zebra-setup-utilities--downloading-fonts-to-a-printer.html), I've downloaded ZebraDesign pro and Zebra Font Downloader but not working.

I don't know what to do...

Comment: You said "but not working." Can you elaborate more? What specifically have you tried? What errors, what symptoms? What is your (simplified) ZPL code you are using?

Comment: Hi, I've already fixed it using Zebra Setup Utilities and ZebraNet Bridge.

Comment: @sopo How did you manage to do it? I want to print Georgian letters, but it prints empty white space only.