# Zebra printer not printing unicode characters

Tags: unicode, zebra-printers, zpl

I'm having some issues with a Zebra printer iMZ220, that when trying to print Unicode characters it simply skips the tag ^CI28 and doesn't print them. What is strange is that it was working at some point but it just doesn't seem to. Here's my ZPL testing code:

^XA 
^PR14,14,14 
^PW406 
^LL70
^PON 
^CI28 
^FO20,20 
^CF0,50 
^FDTéste Acentós € £ $^FS 
^XZ

Any help would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: What tool are you using to send the unicode to the printer?

Comment: see also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040822/unicode-characters-on-zpl-printer/30804262#30804262

Comment: I'm using Bluetooth to send the data.

Comment: Probably you already solved the problem, but did you check that the font you're using in the printer allows unicode characters? If it used to work, it is possible that a unicode-capable font was mapped to one of the standard fonts (A0, A1...) and restarting the printer undid the mapping.