# ^CI doesn't change the codepage in ZPL code or it's the problem of interpretation?

Tags: zpl, codepages, zpl-ii

Here I've got a code on ZPL

^XA
^CWA,A:ARIALR.TTF
^CF20,60
^FO10,130^BCN,100,Y,Y,N^FD[Штрихкод]^FS
^FX ^CF10,20
^AAN,20,10

^CI28^FO10,0^TBN,400,200^FD[Наименование1]^FS
^XZ

The text fields `^FD[Наименование1]^FS` is text on Cyrillic (Russian) and it's displayed incorrectly due to code page, I guess. Tried all types of `^CI` parameters, but in didn't help.
What can be a solvation?

Comment: You are missing `^` before `CI` - is that copy-paste error?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040822/unicode-characters-on-zpl-printer?